# Fastly error when reverse proxying

Tags: nginx, centos, reverse-proxy, contentful

I am trying to setup a caching reverse proxy for Contentful CDN using Nginx

my configuration is as follows:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path  /my/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m       inactive=24h  max_size=1g;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


        server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name my.domain.com;
            server_tokens   off;
            root /my/www/client;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

            auth_basic "Private Property";
            auth_basic_user_file /pass/.htpasswd;


            ssl_certificate /my/ssl/cert.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /my/ssl/key.key;
                ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/LS-dhparam.pem;
                ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
                ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECD$

            location /spaces {
                index index.html index.htm;
                charset utf-8;
                proxy_pass http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/spaceId/entries?access_token=accessTokenValue;
                proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
                proxy_cache STATIC;
                proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
                proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_For;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;

                proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
                proxy_send_timeout 90s;
                proxy_read_timeout 90s;
                proxy_buffer_size 4k;
                proxy_buffers 4 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                send_timeout 90s;

            }
        }
}
```

Where of course the spaceId and accessTokenValue are the appropriate ones

I then trigger a request on https://my.domain.com/spaces/&content_type=myContent&locale=en

Which returns this error: Fastly error: unknown domain: my.domain.com. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.

It works when I try to use the full url being: http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/spaceId/entries?access_token=accessTokenValue&content_type=myContent&locale=en

Is there something wrong with my nginx configuration or is there something from contentful's side?

Comment: Are you looking to pass the arguments from origin request to the proxy pass? also is the url absolute `https://my.domain.com/spaces/` or you will have additional stuff after that?

Comment: i want to pass the arguments on yes. (You can see the two urls in the example. i want the first one to translate to the second one)

Comment: Then change proxy_pass to `proxy_pass http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/spaceId/entries?access_token=accessTokenValue&$query_string`; See if that helps

Comment: I did,  got a 502 which in the logs stated that my cdn.contentful.com could not be resolved so i added  resolver 8.8.8.8; to it and i'm back to the Fastly error above

Comment: I am writing an article on debugging proxy_pass, will share soon, so you can post additional debugging logs

Comment: To help people debug such issues, I just finished the article and published it few mins ago http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

For this to work. Because when you proxy_pass to `proxy_pass http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/spaceId/entries?access_toke‌​n=accessTokenValue&$‌​query_string`, you want the host name to remain as `cdn.contentful.com` and not change it